# Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection alerts tab not found in new google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I got a mail from google play support

Intent Redirection
Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.

To address this issue, follow the steps in this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en).

So as per the steps given in this link, there must be an alerts tab in, play console which is present in the older version of the play console not with the new one is anyone know where to find the alerts tab in the new google play console.

Comment: have you tried Inbox section?

Comment: Do you have anything listed under Pre-launch report > Security and trust?

Comment: @AmodGokhale yes but there is nothing about this issue

Comment: @anorakgirl, nope nothing is there as well

Comment: @sourabhkarmakar - this is interesting. Can you contact there support team and update there response here?

Comment: @sourabhkarmakar there was nothing there for me either. In the end I contacted policy support asking for the the class name causing the problem and they did respond. Takes 48 hours though :(

Comment: I've contacted the support team but I didn't get any answers from them

Answer (score 0):

I published an app to open beta and received a similar email from Google.
Searching through the Google Play Developer Console, I found the Alert notifications now collated inside the Pre-launch Report tab within Testing. Please see the **screenshot attached below**. Clicking on the errors, gives you further details on the manifest entries that are responsible for the errors.

[image]